# High temperatures and CPU almost always 100%

Tags: ram, cpu, overheating, fan, temperature

For about two weeks I have noticed that the temperatures of my cores have increased and are now stable at 70-86 degrees, which is not normal. The fan is always on 3200/3600 rpm and the processor and ram are almost always at maximum. I have not installed anything or done other operations that could have caused this. Could it only be dust in my notebook? Thank you in advance for the help

This is the result of `atop` into terminal

[image]

Comment: Did you try looking to see what processes/threads are consuming CPU?  I like the atop command but there are many others too that can pinpoint the processes that use the most CPU so you can decide what to do about them next.

Comment: @MettaCrawler Just edited the question with the result of atop

Comment: @MettaCrawler Can I do something using in a right way swappiness?

Comment: Try looking into this: https://www.zdnet.com/article/make-google-chrome-faster-reduce-how-much-ram-it-uses-and-be-more-productive/

Answer (score 1):

Your system is short of RAM and is relying on virtual memory.  Either run fewer apps or do something to increase the amount of RAM like buying more RAM for your computer or getting a bigger computer.

I know this because `atop` is showing high `swout`.  Paging out is bad, paging in is usually harmless by comparison.  The scanning rate is also high, the system scans for pages to scavenge when it is short of free RAM.

My experience hearkens back when the BSD `vmstat` had an `sr` column (and Sun copied this feature into the SysVR4 Solaris). The `sr` was "scanning rate" (for [LRU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm#Least_recently_used) pages).  It was the most critical column to pay attention to as it would only go high when the system was starving for memeory.  Linux didn't get it at first, their `vmstat` never had an `sr` but things are starting to get back there, the `dstat --adv-mem` feature was recently added and it looks at scanning rate.  Linux proper (the kernel, that is) has scanning instrumentation, see `grep -i scan /proc/vmstat`.